# Shrink size of footnote asterisk

Tags: footnotes, fontsize

I am trying to shrink the size of the asterisk when using a footnote. [Minimal example](https://www.overleaf.com/project/603a8357d2827e0185964b45):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}


\newcommand{\mytitle}{{\huge{A title\symbolfootnote[1]{A footnote}
}}}
\title{Amsmath example}
\author{ShareLaTeX Templates}
\date{June 2017}

\begin{document}

\mytitle

\end{document}
```

This creates a huge asterisk (obviously). I would like to have a smaller asterisk. I tried to move the symbolfootnote out of the Huge env but then it looks as if it is placed in the middle of the text and not superscripted (it technically is still superscripted, but given the smaller fontsize it looks as if it wasn't).

Comment: `\Huge` is not an environment, but a declaration that takes no arguments.

Comment: Without a working example, how are we to know, for example, how `\symbolfootnote` is defined?  Or in what documentclass this behavior occurs?

Comment: `\footnotesize` is defined for `article`, so you can try inserting that command at the beginning of the definition of `\thefootnote`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution proposal stems from [barbara's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585842/shrink-size-of-footnote-asteriks#comment1472407_585842); I've inserted the "symbol footnote mark" using `\textsuperscript`, which allows you to adjust the font size to suit your needs, while the footnote text is inserted using your (renamed) definition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\symbolfootnotetext[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup%
    \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
    \footnotetext[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{{%
  \huge A title\textsuperscript{\footnotesize *}%
  \symbolfootnotetext[1]{A footnote}%
}}

\begin{document}

\mytitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of the footnotemark symbol is defined in the `\@makefnmark` macro. It is by default printed in `\normalsize`. You can for example modify it to `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\makeatletter
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup%
    \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\footnotesize\@thefnmark}}}% <-- changed to \footnotesize
    \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
    \footnote[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mytitle}{{%
  \huge A title\symbolfootnote[1]{A footnote}%
}}


\begin{document}

\mytitle

\end{document}
```

[image]