# Custom asterisk for amino acid names

Tags: superscripts, protein

I am writing a report where I would like to reduce the time taken to format amino acids and use for the rest of my PhD. I created a command that takes 2 arguments and one optional to format amino acid residues such as `αLys232`. Some of the amino acids have had post-translational modifications and need referencing with an asterisk after the name (Lys) and before the position number (232) like `αLys*232`. However, the spacing is not desirable using just `*` and I was wondering if there were more aesthetic solutions using `tikz` or another method I am not aware of.

This is how my MWE currently looks:

[image]

The one with the normal asterisk has too much space between the name and number (to be expected). The one with `\textsuperscript` from an answer by @Werner to [Shrink size of footnote asterisk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585874/273733) would look better with the asterisk positioned a bit more to the left but not directly over the `s` like an accent. I used the search term `asterisk` in the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List – Symbols accessible from LaTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) but couldn't find an asterisk accent that looks how I would like. This is (poorly drawn and) what I would like:

[image]

How can I shift the `\textsuperscript` asterisk more to the left to reduce space between the name (Lys) and number or via another method please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textgreek}

\newcommand\normalAsterisk[2]{\MakeUppercase#1*#2}
\newcommand\wernerAsterisk[2]{\MakeUppercase#1\textsuperscript{\footnotesize *}#2} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585874/273733
\newcommand\withoutAsterisk[2]{\MakeUppercase#1#2}
\newcommand\greekAsterisk[3][]{#1\MakeUppercase#2#3}

\begin{document}

\noindent Foo bar baz \greekAsterisk[\textalpha]{lys}{232}.\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
This is without the asterisk & \withoutAsterisk{lys}{232} \\
This is with the normal asterisk & \normalAsterisk{lys}{232} \\
This is with \verb|\textsuperscript| & \wernerAsterisk{lys}{232} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math mode asterisk is centered around the math axis

* versus ∗

(the rendering above is just to show the idea).

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\aas}{% AminoAcidStar
  \textsuperscript{$*$}%
}

\begin{document}

Lys\aas 232

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to reduce the space around the asterisk, you can experiment different values in the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\aas}{% AminoAcidStar
  \textsuperscript{$\mkern-1mu*\mkern-1.5mu$}%
}

\begin{document}

Lys\aas 232

\end{document}
```

[image]

An even smaller symbol (but it seems *too* small)

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\aas}{% AminoAcidStar
  \textsuperscript{$\scriptstyle\mkern-1mu*\mkern-1.5mu$}%
}

\begin{document}

Lys\aas 232

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the font size of the asterisk but also the font size of the superscript to control a bit also the height of the symbol, and use a `\makebox` to control  the space  between Lys and 232 according to your taste. If that is not enough, you can always use also `\kern` and/or a  `\raisebox` to fine tune the x and/or y position of the asterik, respectively. Example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\wernerAsterisk[2]{\MakeUppercase#1\textsuperscript{\footnotesize *}#2} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585874/273733
\begin{document}
Lys232\par
\wernerAsterisk{lys}{232}\par
Lys{\footnotesize\textsuperscript{\makebox[2pt]{\tiny *}}}232\par 
Lys{\small\textsuperscript{\makebox[0pt]{\tiny\kern-.15em *}}}232\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could tick both answers as they were helpful, I hope this is fine, thanks a lot for the help :)