# LaTeX3 - Use of \__seq_use_setup:w doesn't match its definition

Tags: expl3

I am wanting to produce a simple package called `aminosymb` for CTAN as I have macros for typesetting amino acids and residue numbers (with optional symbols above the residue name like `*`, improved from an old question: [Custom asterisk for amino acid names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675299)). I want to write the package in `expl3` but my efforts are inadequate so far. I have the following non-working MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\AminoAcidPrinter}{mm}
    {
        \aminoacid_printer:n { #1 #2 }
    }

\str_new:N \s__aminoacid_printer_str

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aminoacid_printer:n
    {
        \str_clear:N \s__aminoacid_printer_str
        \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__aminoacid_printer_str_add:n
        \str_use:Nn \s__aminoacid_printer_str
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aminoacid_printer_str_add:n
    {
    \str_put_right:Nx \s__aminoacid_printer_str
    {
        \str_case:nn { #1 }
        {
        {HIS}{His}
        {His}{His}
        {H}{His}
        {h}{His}
        }
    }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent\AminoAcidPrinter{h}{442}\newline
\AminoAcidPrinter{HIS}{442}\newline
\AminoAcidPrinter{His}{442}\newline
\AminoAcidPrinter{H}{442}\newline
\end{document}
```

All four options should print out the same output i.e. `His 442`. The code itself doesn't work with the first error being

```
Undefined control sequence.
\aminoacid_printer:n ...ter_str_add:n \str_use:Nn 
                                                  \s__aminoacid_printer_str
```

which whilst being informative, I am not sure how to proceed nor how to manage a second argument within the `\NewDocumentCommand`. I am not even sure if I should be using `\s__` for string or if this is a token/other datatype. How can I make this document compile and print out `His 442` for all four varying inputs please?

I am new to `expl3` and have been reading through the [LaTeX3 Interfaces](https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) but it is a steep learning curve and I wouldn't mind a working basic document I can build on to adapt my macros for `expl3` plus helpful hints with respect to this MWE please.

Comment: The prefix should be `l`, `g`, or `c` indicating local, global or constant definition, in this case I expect `l`

Comment: there is no `\str_use:Nn`, did you mean to use `\str_use:N`?

Comment: the error message seems clear you used `\str_use:Nn` which is not defined, what did you want this to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I used that due to the second argument and then accidentally left it in, it compiles after changing it now although I am not sure how to use the second argument in it now, should I replicate `\str_use:N` for the 2nd argument?

Comment: @UdiFogiel yes I meant that, my mistake I thought I needed 2 for the second argument

Comment: `\aminoacid_printer:n { #1 #2 }` just concatenates the two arguments, so it would be simpler and equivalent to just have one argument in your main command, currently `\AminoAcidPrinter{His}{442}` is the same as `\AminoAcidPrinter{His442}{}`

Comment: `\aminoacid_printer:n` only has one argument so I am not sure what you mean by " I am not sure how to use the second argument "

Comment: @DavidCarlisle like I mentioned in the question, this is all extremely new to me, I think I have misread or misapplied what I have read in the documentation. I need to read quite a bit more but wanted a document that could compile to practice on, I thought the code would run as it was (which it did not) hence the Q

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146239/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-jamest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not at all clear what you want this code to do, but this runs without error

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\AminoAcidPrinter}{mm}
    {
        \aminoacid_printer:nn { #1 }{ #2 }
    }

\str_new:N \l__aminoacid_printer_str

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aminoacid_printer:nn
    {
        \str_clear:N \l__aminoacid_printer_str
        \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__aminoacid_printer_str_add:n
        \str_use:N \l__aminoacid_printer_str
         ???
        \str_clear:N \l__aminoacid_printer_str
        \tl_map_function:nN { #2 } \__aminoacid_printer_str_add:n
        \str_use:N \l__aminoacid_printer_str
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aminoacid_printer_str_add:n
    {
    \str_put_right:Nx \l__aminoacid_printer_str
    {
        \str_case:nn { #1 }
        {
        {HIS}{His}
        {His}{His}
        {H}{His}
        {h}{His}
        }
    }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent\AminoAcidPrinter{h}{442}\newline
\AminoAcidPrinter{HIS}{442}\newline
\AminoAcidPrinter{His}{442}\newline
\AminoAcidPrinter{H}{442}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JamesT well you asked for a compilable example you could experiment with and hopefully this provides that. It is hard to match any  of this code with your requirement which seems to be simply to print `#1~#2` with no loops. This code loops through each letter and prints `His` if `h` or `H` appears , so in each case you get `His` for the first argument and  nothing for the second

Comment: Thanks, I will accept as it is a basis to start from and answered the question, think I need to read significantly more before I ask again, this issue was fixed too quickly!